# Need Grouping of UITableView in Alphabetical Order with Expand/Collapse functionality

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to implement a `UITableView` which has alphabetical order same as in Contact App and then on selection of any cell it should get expand. Below is my code for Alphabetical order.

```
    var houseHoldArray = ["Ahouse", "AAhouse", "Bhouse", "BBhouse", "BBBhouse", "CHouse", "CCHouse", "CCHouse", "DHouse", "EHouse", "HHouse", "XHouse", "ZHouse"]
    var houseHoldAlphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "H", "X", "Z"]
    var houseHoldArrayOfDic = [
                                "A": ["Ahouse", "AAhouse"],
                                "B": ["Bhouse", "BBhouse", "BBBhouse"],
                                "C": ["CHouse", "CCHouse", "CCHouse"],
                                "D": ["DHouse"],
                                "E": ["EHouse"],
                                "H": ["HHouse"],
                                "X": ["XHouse"],
                                "Z": ["ZHouse"]
                              ]



public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return houseHoldArrayOfDic[houseHoldAlphabet[section]]!.count
}

public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return houseHoldAlphabet.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return houseHoldAlphabet[section]
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    if cell == nil {
         cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    cell?.textLabel?.text = houseHoldArrayOfDic[houseHoldAlphabet[indexPath.section]]?[indexPath.row]
            // Configure the cell...

    return cell!
}

func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return houseHoldAlphabet
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
    return houseHoldAlphabet.index(of: title)!
}
```

Now suppose if I select `Ahouse` then it should get expanded and display the subCells. Each Row should be expandable.

I am aware about two methods to apply expand and collapse on UITableView

1. Using TapGesture:- Adding tapGesture on section -> inserting rows on that section -> reloading selected section
2. Using didSelectRowAtIndex:- Taking only one cell under each section (section height can be 0) -> on selection of this row write the code to add new rows and reload section in didSelectRowAtIndex.

Both of the above two methods would not give proper animation if try to reload section as I have multiple rows (which can be expanded) in each section.

Also the above two methods work for tapGesture on Section OR Single Cell in each Section. Not sure how to implement for multiple rows in a section.

Need Suggestion!!

Comment: Take a look at this sample project: [CollapsibleTableSection](https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section)

Comment: That may help you : https://github.com/genkernel/TreeView AND https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried option 2 using `tableView.beginUpdates()` followed by `tableView.endUpdates()` instead of `tableView.reloadData`? This will trigger the height changes without reloading the whole dataSource